# regex search for valid time

Tags: python, regex

My data(csv) has following values - user_id, time_free as following.

```
user1   Mon-Wed 10:30 am - 1:00 pm
user2   Mon-Thu 1:00 pm - 5:00 pm , Fri 10:30 am - 2:00 pm
```

I am trying to use regex in Python. I am not getting desired results.
I am expecting to get Mon and time in separate groups.

```
import csv
import re

with open('myfile.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        pattern = re.compile("([A-Z][a-z][a-z])\S-(\S?)\d?\d:\d\d ] [ap][m]")
        for (l, n) in re.findall(pattern,row[1]):
            print(l)
```

Comment: Try debugging it at https://regex101.com, you should pretty quickly see why it doesn't match.

Comment: See [`\b([A-Z][a-z]{2})\s*-\s*[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s*(\d?\d:\d\d *[ap][m])`](https://regex101.com/r/jEZIqV/2)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @paddu I added an answer since I feel it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\b([A-Z][a-z]{2})\s*-\s*[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s*(\d?\d:\d\d\s*[aApP][Mm])'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jEZIqV/4)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([A-Z][a-z]{2})` - Group 1 (`Mon`): an uppercase ASCII letter and 2 lowercase ones
- `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `[A-Z][a-z]{2}` - an uppercase ASCII letter and 2 lowercase ones
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d?\d:\d\d\s*[aApP][Mm])` - Group 2 (`time`):

  - `\d?` - an optional digit
  - `\d:\d\d` - any digit, `:`, 2 digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    -`[aApP][Mm]` - `AM` or `PM` (case insensitive).